# I want to pass two variable from an selected row as array in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I have a table with two columns, and I would like to return each selected row as an array variable for a SQL query.

I am not sure how to do it in C#.
I edit the code that is written for passing one column data. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectionCompleteCheckBox.Checked == true)
    {
        List<string> studyIDs = new List<string>();
        List<string> ASSAYDESCRIPTIONs = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in AssayData.SelectedRows)
        {
            try
            {
                studyIDs.Add(row.Cells["STUDYID"].Value.ToString());
                ASSAYDESCRIPTIONs.Add(row.Cells["ASSAYDESCRIPTION"].Value.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                //Do something?
            }
            if (studyIDs.Count > 0)
            {
                controller.GetResult(studyIDs, ASSAYDESCRIPTIONs);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void GetResult(Array{studyIDs,ASSAYDESCRIPTIONs})
{
    EventArg<DataTable> e;
    e = new EventArg<DataTable>(database.GetResults(studyIDs, ASSAYDESCRIPTIONs));
    if (SelectedDataUpdate != null)
    {
        SelectedDataUpdate.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it is better that you explain what you want to do with that data because this code seems to be totally unclear (and uncompilable)

Comment: you want to return an array, array of strings ? objects ? you know how to create a `List` from `SelectedRows`, you can convert any `List` into array by simply calling `List.toArray()`

Comment: As @Steve has alluded to a [mcve] would be nice here.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to create a class to make it easier to follow.

for instance:

```
public class TestResult
{
 public string StudyID {get;set;}
 public string AssayDescription {get;set;} 
}
```

Now when you get the data you can construct a list of `TestResult`s.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (SelectionCompleteCheckBox.Checked == true)
  {
      List<TestResult> results = new List<TestResult>();
      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in AssayData.SelectedRows)
      {
          try
          {
              var temp = new TestResult();
              temp.StudyID = row.Cells["STUDYID"].Value.ToString()
              temp.AssyDescription = row.Cells["ASSAYDESCRIPTION"].Value.ToString()
              results.Add(temp);
          }
          catch (Exception ee)
          {
              //Do something?
          }
      }
      if (results.Count > 0)
      {
          controller.GetResult(results);
      }

}
```

**Note I'm not really sure how this method is working but an approach may be.**

```
public void GetResult(List<TestResult> results)
{

    foreach(var test in results)
    {
      //update result data table.

    }

}
```

Comment: I am trying to pass the two variables together to do an SQL query on the Where cause. so the two variables must be read together in order to retrieve and update table. how can I call which out each Variable on its position?

Comment: I haven't seen your `database.GetResults(studyIDs, ASSAYDESCRIPTIONs)` method so I'm not sure what type of changes you would need to make.  `List<TestResults>` in my example contains the information.  You could loop through the values and update.